# Gamemaker studio: My enemies jump out of the room but only when they collide with the left wall

Tags: debugging, game-development, game-maker

My  jumping enemies jump out of the room. They collide with the right wall and bounce off correctly. however when they collide with a left wall they jump out of the room and fall out. Please help. Thanks. This is in gamemaker studio 2 and I am creating a platformer game.

```
//Gravity and movement
vsp = vsp + grv;
//Dont walk off the edge

if (grounded == true) and (afraidofheights == true) and (!place_meeting(x+sign(hsp),y+1,oWall))
{
    hsp = -hsp;
}


//Horizontal collision
if (place_meeting(x+walksp,y,oWall))
{
    while (!place_meeting(x+sign(walksp),y,oWall))
    {
        //x = x + sign(walksp);
    }
    hsp = -walksp;
}

x = x + hsp;

//Vertical collision
if (place_meeting(x,y+vsp,oWall))
{
    while (!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vsp),oWall))
    {
        y = y + sign(vsp);
    }
    vsp = -jumpheight;  
}

y = y + vsp;

//Animations
//if the enemy is off the ground they use jumping and falling animations
if (!place_meeting(x,y+1,oWall))
{
    grounded = false;
    sprite_index = jumpsprite;
    image_speed = 0;
    if (sign(vsp) > 0) image_index = 1; else image_index = 0;
}
else
{
    grounded = true;
    image_speed = 1;
    //if the player is standing still plays idle animation
    if (hsp == 0)
    {
        sprite_index = idlesprite;  
    }
    //if the player is moving plays running animation
    else
    {
        sprite_index = runsprite;
    }
    
}

//Changes direction of sprite
if (hsp!= 0 ) image_xscale = sign(hsp) *size;
image_yscale = size;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be your enemy sprite origins. GameMaker calculations are done respective to the object's current sprite's origin point, so if that point is different between two sprites or not at the sprite's center, it might move the object in undesirable ways.